# Running a python script as part of a cmake build

Tags: cmake

I'm using cmake for the first time and am just not having luck finding examples that help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. The functionality seems very basic, but nothing I've tried thus far has given me any meaningful output or error.

I have a PRELOAD command for a document, and this works fine as long as the document has already been created.

```
set(variable_name
       PRELOAD ${_source_directory}/Documents/output.txt AS output.txt
)
```

But I want the document generation(which is accomplished via a python script) to be part of the cmake build process as well. The command I want to run is

```
python_script.py ${_source_directory}/Documents/input.txt 
                 ${_source_directory}/Documents/output.txt
```

and I want that to run before the PRELOAD statement is executed.

Here's an example of what I've tried

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${_source_directory}/Documents/output.txt
    COMMAND python_script.py ${_source_directory}/Documents/input.txt
                             ${_source_directory}/Documents/output.txt
)
set(variable_name
       PRELOAD ${_source_directory}/Documents/output.txt AS output.txt
)
```

But that gives me the same error as if the add_custom_command wasn't even there ("No rule to make target ${_source_directory}/Documents/output.txt").

Comment: I am not familiar with this `set(... PRELOAD ...)` syntax. In fact, I couldn't find it [in the docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html). What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Well I guess right here with the PRELOAD, it just adds the filename as part of the string contained in variable_name. Later on, that variable is parsed and each filename is used to read the actual file. I just need the python script to run and actually generate the file before it is used later.

Comment: what's the output of `cmake --version`?

Comment: In fact, that `set` statement will just create a list such as `'PRELOAD;/Documents/output.txt;AS;output.txt'` (with `_source_directory` set to "")

Answer (score 0):

You do/understand it wrong. As it was mentioned in comments `set()` has nothing like `PRELOAD`.

The correct way is to use `add_custom_target()` which would produce an `output.txt` in desired directory and then `add_dependencies()` for target you want to build and which would use the `output.txt`.